# Excel repeated times table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to have a column with the three times table in an excel spreadsheet, however I would like each term to be repeated 4 times i.e:

```
3
3
3
3
6
6
6
6
9
9
9
9
12
12
12
12
...
```

when I type this down a column and then select & drag to autofill it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Enter this formula and fill it down.

`=INT((ROW()+2)/4)*3`

- `... * 3` - you get multiplies of 3
- `INT(.../4)` - everything is repeated 4 times
- `ROW()+2` - shifting results to start in the right row (if you don't completely understand this, then you can even try multiple values to get it right).

[image]